# Is there any BLAS routine for take abs/tanh/sin for a whole C-vector?

Tags: c, deep-learning, blas, activation-function

Assuming that we have a C vector `real myVector[50] = {3,2.2,31...}` and I want to turn take the abs, than or sin or why not `max(0, m)` or sigmoid.

Is there any BLAS routine for that, or do I need to use a for-loop? Can I improve the for-loop if there is no BLAS routines for what I'm seeking?

[image]

Comment: No there is not. Implement yourself. What precision are you interested in?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour 0.001 only. I have made a file here: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Deeplearning2C/blob/master/Deeplearning2CApp/src/main/resources/se/danielmartensson/views/blas/activation.c

Comment: You can accelerate that code on `AVX`-capable CPUs easily by factor 8:
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/SIMDTraits.hpp
Now, the above code is C++, but you should be able to get the idea. I am using the C-API for the vector intrinsics for amd64 CPUs.